# Foreign Key Prefix to Auto_Increment Primary Key (INT)

Tags: mysql, sql

#### Skip down for TL:DR version

Currently designing a Horse-riding class booking function for a Club's website.
Designing the SQL database from scratch using phpMyAdmin. Members join the club as per family basis - Meaning each unique "Family_ID" would contain multiple members within each one.

The club only wants users to login with their Family_ID and through that one login the user would be able to book a riding class for any of the members within the family. was wondering if it's possible to give each member a unique ID by referencing the Foreign Key (Family_ID). So each member would have a unique ID based on their Family_ID. Example Listed below.

---

When a new family registers for the club - they fill in paper forms which an admin will enter their details into the existing database, currently the members don't have an ID, just details kept within each Family_ID. Was thinking of a work-around where when a new member is being added the form would have an auto-fill input box that adds '01'/'02'/etc to the ends of family_id.

---

## TL:DR

SQL - phpMyAdmin
Multiple Members within a "Family_ID"

1. Multiple Members share a "Family_ID" (Foreign Key from "Family" Table)
2. Each Member to have a Unique ID - "Member_ID" (That uses the Family_ID as a prefix)

**Example**

Family_ID = 0024

Member_ID = 002401 (Unique Member_ID Auto_increment using last two digits)

---

*My first post so I apologize if I left out any necessary information, Thank you for your answers.*

---

Comment: You can do this, but it requires writing a trigger.  Normally, you would just use an auto-incremented primary key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - A mysql trigger that would reference the foreign key (Family_ID) and input 01/02/03 to the ends of it before inserting into the Database?

Comment: Normally Family have own primary ID and member have own primary and linked between this two with foreign key such.. Family(Family_ID(PK)), Member(Member_ID(PK), fam_id(FK)).. For example family table Family_ID = 123, while in member table Member_ID=1 and fam_id=123.. It seem you are trying to customize the primary id for the member table where the last digit two digit is primary id for family. THis cannot be done when you are activated the auto_increment feature

Comment: @parkway , ok so it would be possible if auto_increment is turned off, and instead have a set of code to reference the Family_ID and create a unique id for the member before the record is inserted?

Comment: @CestllyCoronado yes autoincrement need to be turn off. then you get the last inserted unique id from family table to generate the new id for the member table.. but i recommend u need a autoincrement for the member table.. maybe u can use other attribute to assigned as primary key(auto increament) for the member table.. while the member_ID is manually generated

Comment: @parkway So you would still recommend me to have a Primary Key that is auto_increment, Just for the sake of Indexing? 
And the manually generated "Member_ID" would be set to a Unique Key?

Comment: yes add 1 column called(id or others name) for member table as primary key with auto increment. then member_id in member table generate manually.